# How to make eclipse (neon 2) work better with goovy/grails?

Tags: eclipse, groovy

Some time ago I edited a node project in grails. Now every project, even if it has nothing to do with node, shows 5 node files when I do "new" to create a new file. (type script, node project file etc).

I now only have a grails 3 projects in Eclipse, with the usual groovy eclipse plugins installed.

When I want to create a new groovy file (e.g. a domain object, controller etc), I go to file->new, and I only see the 5 node entries, plus a few generic ones.

Is there any way to make it show "groovy class" in the new list, and not show the node related ones?

I thought facets might be for this, but my project has no facets configured (and eclipse still thinks its node), and there are no grails/groovy type facets).

Any suggestions?  Not a show stopper obviously.

E.g. can I create my own facet without coding, or can I influence which file types appear on create new by project?

I could open up a DOS command box and do the grails command to create the classes, but his is more work, especially as it creates broken tests which have to be manually deleted after (until such point as we need tests)

Intellij ultimate is unfeasibly expensive, so that is not an option.

Comment: As far as I remember Eclipse is extra-bad when it comes to Groovy support, so you might be at loss if you require to use that PoC.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to customize what appears in the New drop-down using *Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective...*.  In the dialog that comes up, click the *Shortcuts* tab and you can check or uncheck items that will show in the New drop-down.

You can also edit what options will show for the Show View and Open Perspective sub-menus from here.